# Determine if a user has permissions to edit the registry?

Tags: c#, registry

I'm writing a program that edits the registry using c#

I would like to check if the user has access to edit when the program loads. What is the best way to check in c#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get registry write permissions in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721145/how-to-get-registry-write-permissions-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

Each node in the registry has its own ACL (Access Credential List). There is not a single right.

Commonly, each application will have its own registry node, either in the HKLM hive or in HKCU hive, or a combination of both.

In the former case, the user has to be administrator of the computer, in the latter the user can read/write its own registry.

To check the actual access permission, you can use the [`RegistryKey.GetAccessControl` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7fwef5z.aspx).

However, as stated, you have to have at least the Read permissions to call this method.

Comment: I'm doing 
           var temp = registryKey.GetAccessControl();
but in temp it's not give me a value to saying read or write?

Comment: var temp = registryKey.GetAccessControl().AccessRightType

Answer (score 1):

Try to open a `RegistryKey` with write access. If it gives you an `Exception`, you don't have permission.
You could probably even specifiy which Exception to a certain one which says you don't have permission.

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
    Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"PATH\TO\STUFF", true);
    // Have write permissions.
}
catch {
    // Do not have write permissions.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A user shouldn't have access to edit "the full registry" they should only have permissions to edit certain keys within the registry.

You would be best doing a try catch system

```
try{
     // Do registry edit
} 
catch {
     Console.Log("Sorry you don't have permission to edit this key");
}
```

Each user is different and can have access to some parts, all parts or no parts of the registry using the windows ACL.

Have a peek at the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721145/how-to-get-registry-write-permissions-in-c-sharp) here.