# Registry getValue with C#

Tags: c#, registry

I would like to read value in the registry using C#, if the values are not in the registry I create it. I have a reading problem:

```
 RegistryKey regKey1 = Registry.CurrentUser;
 regKey1 = regKey1.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\PNMDISPATCHER");

 if (regKey1 != null)
 {
  textBoxTaux1.Text = regKey1.GetValue("Taux1").ToString();
 }
```

I have the `NullReferenceException` when execute the `GetValue` function.
My values are in the registry, so why i get this error?

Comment: go over this first http://stackoverflow.com/a/721190/67505

Comment: Try to fetch a value for some other key in similar location. If it works, you know you got your name/value pair or the path wrong. Also, you can give a try to OpneSubKey which gives read only access. Also, check if you have access to the registry and admin privileges on the machine with the current account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the RegistryKey.GetValue is returning null and cannot do .ToString()

**Taken from MSDN for RegistryKey.GetValue:**

> Retrieves the value associated with the specified name. Returns null
>   if the name/value pair does not exist in the registry.

Answer (score 1):

Well, apparently you didn't get the path right..

`GetValue` returns a `Null` when the key isn't found. Also check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdf576x1

Can you debug through it and double check that the path you want to see, is indeed in the regKey1 variable at the textbox line?

Comment: My path are OK ! I don't understand :( In addition, i have values in the key, if i use the registry editor.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the NullReferenceException is for textBoxTaux1? Please post the call stack for the exception which should make this clear. You can use Exception.ToString() to get this.